# Flyway is there a way to use it throught MAVEN AND API in same project

Tags: flyway

In our project I would like to use flyway framework for Database delivery process

knowing that

A) the delivery team and the application don't have the same USER to access the database
(delivery team use database login that allow create/truncate table) but the application have no permission for doing that

--> API will just be use to check version

--> delivery team will use maven to launch the migration process

B) We wants to use a specific "Migration" Table (not schema_version)

C) to avoid any issue I would appreciate to this setup (name of the table) to be shared between maven and API

1) Is there a way to share some part of the setup (name of the table, jdbcUrl) to be shared between maven and API

2)Is there a simpler way in the API to check if the database is up to date 
I use something like that

if (flyway.info().pending().length > 0) System.out.println("Database not patched")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes. Just configure them identically. Property names are the same.

2) No, this is the simplest way available right now.